# Form script not updating MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, forms

I have a very simple form on a webpage. It contains a product description followed by a textbox (Quantity box) where the user can enter a new quantity, and then a price next to the textfield.

When the update button is clicked, it should update the database.

The **name**'s of the textfields correspond to the product that they are entering a new value (quantity) for.

Zero errors are being generated. I have used print_r($_POST); to see what's being sent, if anything:

I would greatly appreciate any help at all, thank you so much.

jase

Comment: +1 why the downvote? Looks like a perfectly good question to me.

Answer (score 0):

$key and $value are not defined, since your for loop is naming the variable $id and $data

foreach($_POST as **$id**=>**$data**)

Comment: Thanks, I have also tried $id=>$data. Exact same thing happens: Nothing.

Comment: could you do a echo $id . "->".$data. also can you please post the table definition?

Comment: print_r($id); and print_r($data); reveal that the correct information is in the variables $id and $data. However, nothing gets added to the database.

Comment: can you please post the table definition? is the sessionid column required?

Comment: are you sure you are connected to the correct database? i noticed on the link you provided that you are using the mysse db

Comment: I am posting the Table Def. now, and the sessionid column is absolutely required :)

Comment: Yeah, I have the correct connection/ When I pasted the code on stackoverflow, I just rearranged the database credentials and connection info ;) - I didn't realise mysse was an actual database lol. I am using MySQL

Comment: Sorry, my internet screwed up. Here's the Table def.: **'sessions', 'CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `sessionid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'**

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can try to help troubleshoot. Try using [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) with the key variable. If the column's are integers, try removing single quotes and casting the value to insure value is an integer. For example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO sessions (product, qty) VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "', " . (int) $data . ")") or die(mysql_error());
```